# SQL query results null in relation to another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables (SQL Server).
Table 1. ComentListaDef (means Comments)
Table 2. ListaDefeito (means DefectList)
Table 3. RespostaComentListaDef (means Answer in relation to Comments)

I need to do a query that brings to me all the "ComentListaDef.Comentarios" that "RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor" has not answered.
I want to see all the "ComentListaDef.Comentarios" that is null in relation to "RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor".

I'm trying to do this query but it's not working.

"ComentListaDef" means "Comments" and "RespostaComentListaDef" means "Answer". I'm trying to list all the comments that the Author with Id = ? (RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor) did not answer.

```
SELECT ComentListaDef.Comentarios, COUNT(RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor) 
FROM ComentListaDef   
INNER JOIN ListaDefeito ON ComentListaDef.IdListaDefeitos = ListaDefeito.Id  
LEFT JOIN RespostaComentListaDef on ComentListaDef.Id = RespostaComentListaDef.IdComentListaDef
WHERE ListaDefeito.IdRevisor = 1075  
AND ComentListaDef.IdListaDefeitos = 36  
AND RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor = 1072  
GROUP BY ComentListaDef.Comentarios HAVING COUNT(RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor) = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join to the comments on author and only return items which are null.  (This is functionally the same to "not in", but I think it is clearer if you are used to working with joins)

```
SELECT *
FROM CommentListaDef
LEFT JOIN RespostaComentListaDef on ComentListaDef.Id = RespostaComentListaDef.IdComentListaDef AND RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor =1072  
WHERE RespostaComentListaDef is null
```

Comment: it worked well! thank you!! I had to add more things for what I want but it worked good! thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly: you want all the comments for which there are no answers.

A `not exists` condition should work:

```
select whatever
from Comments c
where not exists (select 1 from answers a where a.CommentId = c.Id
                                             and a.AuthorId = @AuthorId)
```

Comment: Exactly. I want all the comments for which there are no answers from the Author with Id = ? (RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor)

Comment: @Victor so add additional conditions to the inner query, as per the edit I'm about to add.